# Windows XP keeps on restarting

Tags: windows-xp, desktop-computer

My desktop computer keeps restarting and I don't know why. Can somebody please help me?

I have tried removing the plug, cleaning the fan and holding the power button for ten seconds, but nothing worked!

I use Windows XP.

It goes till the Windows XP logo with the loading bar and then it shutsdown and do it again. I tried leaving it the whole day, but it still didn't work.

It instantly reboots.

I tried booting into safe mode, but it just did the same.

Ok now I get the following message:

We apologize for the inconvenience, but Windows did not start successfully. A recent hardware or software change might have caused this.

If your computer stopped responding, restarted unexpectedly, or was automatically shut down to protect your files and folders, choose Last Known Good Configuration to revert to the most recent settings that worked.

If a previous startup attempt was interupted due to a power failure or because the Power or Reset button was pressed, or if you aren't sure what caused the problem, choose Start Windows Normally.

```
Safe Mode
Safe Mode with Networking
Safe Mode with Command Prompt
Last Known Good Configuration (your most recent settings that worked)
Start Windows Normally
```

Use the up and down arrow keys to move the highlight to your choice.

Comment: This sounds like a driver problem.  Are you able to boot into `Safe Mode`?

Comment: boot to safe mode using the F8 key, then reboot normally to see if its fixed (seen it happen more than once - it got fixed simply by entering safe mode and rebooting). if it isnt fixed, attempt resuming to an earlier restore point.

Comment: Once I've seen a machine, which had a reset button with faulty contact... it wasn't really fast to find :-)

Comment: Try to boot it with an ubuntu live cd, and let it run for a day from this. You will at least know, if it is hw or sw problem.

Comment: @shlck : you have right, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When you say your computer keeps restarting, do you mean that Windows is doing a clean shutdown and reboot? Or do you mean that your computer instantly reboots? Could you also provide details on what you are doing when this happens? Does this happen after a specified period of time?

Have a look at the System event log. Click on Start > Click on 'Run' and type 'eventvwr' (without quotes) and press Enter. On the left hand side of the window, select System. Check for any Warnings/Errors that happened around the time the computer last rebooted itself.

Thanks

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Okay. So it gets to the XP bootloader screen with Blue/Green scrolling bar and then reboots. This is called a "boot loop". Boot loops can be caused by a large number of things and can be difficult to diagnose. Can you think of any reason why this would have happened Have you installed anything recently? Could you try booting into Safe Mode? To do this, turn your computer off, rapidly tap the F8 key and then turn the computer on. You should be presented with a multiple choice menu, highlight the option that says "Boot into Safe Mode" and then press Enter.

Comment: Thanks for learning me something new, yes I am currently working on web design and developing. I installed IE8, Google Chrome, Notepad++ and Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried booting into safe mode, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please see my edited question

Comment: At this point I would assume that there not much left to try. If you've got an official Microsoft Windows XP CD-ROM you could use this is boot into the Microsoft Windows Recovery Console to perform a file system disk check using "chkdsk /f /p". Refer to this article for more information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314058

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean that your computer keeps rebooting or it keeps turning on automaticly after you shut down and then automaticly shutting down over and over again?

Comment: Though let the tech handle a of the reinstallation.

Comment: To ask questions about the problem, please post a comment. Do not answer.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever the case, press F8 and select safe mode with command prompt
then use the reinstallition command. It should be fine after that. Ask a technition of what the command is since I forgotted that command.